# Locust - Simulating 1000 non-concurrent users over certain period of time

Tags: testing, load-testing, locust

I am trying to simulate 1000 non-concurrent users over a period of time.
The goal is to evenly distribute them and test real life application.
What I'm struggling is finding a way to let user be only alive for certain period of time.

I haven't managed to find anything regarding this topic

Comment: I'm not experienced with locust, but maybe managing user sessions could help you out with your problem, use "logged_at" datetime, + add specific time to log him out by destroying his session.

Comment: Locust will run whatever code you want. How do you want the users to behave? Can you write a regular Python script to do what you want? You can make Locust do the same thing.